# Chrome extension page_action icon not hidden

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am using `background.js` script to hide my `page_action` icon with the following code:

```
    chrome.pageAction.hide(sender.tab.id, function(some) {
        console.log(sender.tab.id);
    });
```

However, the icon is always 'on' and never gets hidden. I do not have any other functionality which enables the icon, and according to page_action [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/pageAction), the icon should be hidden by default.

If I remove my `content script` from `manifest.json`, indeed, the icon is disabled by default.

Here is `manifest.json`:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Chrome Extension",
  "description": "Chrome Extension",
  "minimum_chrome_version": "10.0",
  "version": "1.0",
  "page_action": {
    "default_icon": "logo.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "<all_urls>"
      ],
      "js": [
        "js/vendor.js",
        "js/content_script.js"
      ],
      "css": [
        "js/content_script.css"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": [
      "js/vendor.js",
      "js/background.js"
    ]
  },
  "permissions": [
    "declarativeContent",
    "tabs",
    "webNavigation",
    "storage",
    "activeTab",
    "<all_urls>"
  ]
}
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Usually it's just `sender.tab.id` so why are you using `sender.sender.tab.id`? Also please show your page_action declaration in manifest.json just in case.

Comment: @wOxxOm added. the sender.sender is  a typo, but not the reason for the issue.

Comment: Since you're using declarativeContent I guess you have a rule to show the icon.